# How to remove old device from Safari iCloud Tabs?

Tags: icloud, macbook-pro, accounts

I returned a MacBook to Apple Store, however apparently I forgot to sign out of iCloud and the latest tabs I was browsing still appear in Safari iCloud Tabs of my new MacBook and existing iPad.

I removed the device from icloud.com -> Find My iPhone but it didn't work. Tabs list from my old computer is still there and I am trying to remove it from my devices list. I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Apple's [iCloud Tabs support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5372) (emphasis added):

> If you can't access the device that shared the tab, *the tab will automatically be cleared from the list after 14 days if the tab isn't updated*.

So, any leftover tabs should be gone after two weeks.

Comment: That's cool, let's wait and see.

Answer (score -2):

Read this Article. 
Very Hopeful

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-close-safari-tabs-on-another-icloud-device/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.